# How to set up TODO comment autocomplete

Tags: intellij-idea, todo

Can someone explain the pattern at todo optional tab in intellij [image]

for example :if i type "todo" then I want the "todo" tag should output:

```
//todo this is your code here
```

what should I do?

Comment: you want to have the string "//todo this is your code here" written in place of "todo" when you press tab, correct ? (not sure to have understood well)

Comment: yes  just like : //TODO this is your code here to complete.

Answer (score 5):

The window in your screenshot just controls the icons shown on the left gutter.

What you want is a *live template*:

- open settings > editor > live templates
- choose a category, for example *other*
- press on the "+" on the right, *add template*
- abbreviation: "todo",
  description: anything, 
  template text: "// todo this is your code here"
- choose the applicable contexts, for example Java.
- press ok

Then, in a java code, type todo + tab.

---

[image: intellij settings]

Comment: It worked on editor. For both Ctrl+Enter and Tab.